# Interesting 16x16 grid sum

Tags: java, algorithm, sum

EDIT: Path, not line --- it can wind around and stuff. The path connects adjacent squares. You cannot go diagonally.

Also, my proposed solution was an attempt to take every possible string of 50-digit numbers base 4 - so that, you start at each square, and move left, right, up or down --- in every possible combination 4^50

This problem asks you to find the greatest sum of 50 numbers that can be connected by a path, without going diagonally, in this 16x16 grid:

```
                         {{50,54,46,55,45,56,44,53,47,59,41,60,40,59,41,59},
                          {47,57,46,49,52,46,53,47,53,41,59,40,60,41,59,41},
                          {56,42,54,51,48,54,47,53,53,57,48,54,49,57,46,59},
                          {48,50,52,54,56,58,57,47,48,49,48,47,46,53,52,51},
                          {50,56,50,48,49,50,51,59,42,60,39,62,38,63,38,50},
                          {60,40,50,50,50,50,60,40,55,45,55,45,56,44,56,44},
                          {60,45,46,37,56,50,43,39,50,53,56,39,50,58,39,49},
                          {26,56,54,38,48,50,67,64,32,54,50,49,48,47,46,45},
                          {28,45,35,57,54,34,34,32,64,57,58,74,24,64,34,50},
                          {40,50,60,54,45,56,46,47,35,36,39,27,38,50,51,52},
                          {29,38,47,58,48,37,50,58,37,46,50,50,50,50,50,50},
                          {47,48,49,50,52,65,64,52,49,47,43,47,58,46,30,32},
                          {59,47,47,56,65,34,45,56,75,24,35,45,56,65,50,54},
                          {53,46,35,45,29,46,46,50,23,32,40,46,64,64,64,20},
                          {53,54,56,58,60,43,43,34,34,35,64,30,50,40,49,59},
```

This algorithm tries **random** paths and turns after each of the 50 steps - up, right, down, left - without crossing over itself. It gets me to about 2750, but I need at least 2800 to complete the assignment.
//lol

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class lol
{
private int[][] square = {{50,54,46,55,45,56,44,53,47,59,41,60,40,59,41,59},
                          {47,57,46,49,52,46,53,47,53,41,59,40,60,41,59,41},
                          {56,42,54,51,48,54,47,53,53,57,48,54,49,57,46,59},
                          {48,50,52,54,56,58,57,47,48,49,48,47,46,53,52,51},
                          {50,56,50,48,49,50,51,59,42,60,39,62,38,63,38,50},
                          {60,40,50,50,50,50,60,40,55,45,55,45,56,44,56,44},
                          {60,45,46,37,56,50,43,39,50,53,56,39,50,58,39,49},
                          {26,56,54,38,48,50,67,64,32,54,50,49,48,47,46,45},
                          {28,45,35,57,54,34,34,32,64,57,58,74,24,64,34,50},
                          {40,50,60,54,45,56,46,47,35,36,39,27,38,50,51,52},
                          {29,38,47,58,48,37,50,58,37,46,50,50,50,50,50,50},
                          {47,48,49,50,52,65,64,52,49,47,43,47,58,46,30,32},
                          {59,47,47,56,65,34,45,56,75,24,35,45,56,65,50,54},
                          {53,46,35,45,29,46,46,50,23,32,40,46,64,64,64,20},
                          {53,54,56,58,60,43,43,34,34,35,64,30,50,40,49,59},
                          {52,12,17,50,63,62,62,64,50,51,52,57,43,44,42,69}};                         ;

    public static void main(String [] args)
{
    lol lol1 = new lol();
}
public lol()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> record = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int max =0;
    for(int count = 0; count<10000; count++)
    {
        for(int startx=0; startx<16; startx++)
        {
            for(int starty =0; starty<16; starty++)
            {
                int[] pos = new int[2];
                pos[0] = starty;
                pos[1] = startx;
                ArrayList<Integer> past = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                int total = 0;

                for(int i=0; i<50; i++)
                {
                    int random = (int)(Math.random()*4);
                    int switchcount = 0;
                    past.add(100*pos[0] + pos[1]);
                    total+= square[pos[0]][pos[1]];

                    if(random == 0)
                    {
                        if(pos[0] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0]-1)*100+pos[1],past))
                        {
                            random++;
                            switchcount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pos[0]--;

                        }
                    }
                    if(random == 1)
                    {
                        if(pos[0] == 15 || checkexists((pos[0]+1)*100+pos[1],past))
                        {
                            random++;
                            switchcount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pos[0]++;

                        }
                    }
                    if(random == 2)
                    {
                        if(pos[1] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0])*100+pos[1]-1,past))
                        {
                            random++;
                            switchcount++;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pos[1]--;

                        }
                    }
                    if(random == 3)
                    {
                        if(pos[1] == 15 || checkexists((pos[0])*100+pos[1]+1,past))
                        {
                            if(switchcount >= 3)
                            {
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                random = 0;
                                if(pos[0] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0]-1)*100+pos[1],past))
                                {
                                    random++;
                                    switchcount++;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    pos[0]--;

                                }
                                if(random == 1)
                                {
                                    if(pos[0] == 15 || checkexists((pos[0]+1)*100+pos[1],past))
                                    {
                                        random++;
                                        switchcount++;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        pos[0]++;

                                    }
                                }

                                if(random == 2)
                                {
                                    if(pos[1] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0])*100+pos[1]-1,past))
                                    {
                                        break;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        pos[1]--;

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            pos[1]++;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (total>max)
                {
                    max = total;
                    record = past;
                }







            }
        }
    }
    for(int p = 0; p<record.size(); p++)
    {
        System.out.println(record.get(p));
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n" + max);

}
public boolean checkexists(int pos, ArrayList<Integer> past)
{
    for(int i=0; i<past.size(); i++)
    {
        if(past.get(i) == pos)
        {
            //System.out.println("TRUE");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

This is my attempt at a full solution - it attempt to take every possible string of 50-digit numbers base 4 - so that, you start at each square, and move left, right, up or down --- in every possible combination 4^50

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

    public class lol2
     {
     private int[][] square =      {{50,54,46,55,45,56,44,53,47,59,41,60,40,59,41,59},
                              {47,57,46,49,52,46,53,47,53,41,59,40,60,41,59,41},
                          {56,42,54,51,48,54,47,53,53,57,48,54,49,57,46,59},
                          {48,50,52,54,56,58,57,47,48,49,48,47,46,53,52,51},
                          {50,56,50,48,49,50,51,59,42,60,39,62,38,63,38,50},
                          {60,40,50,50,50,50,60,40,55,45,55,45,56,44,56,44},
                          {60,45,46,37,56,50,43,39,50,53,56,39,50,58,39,49},
                          {26,56,54,38,48,50,67,64,32,54,50,49,48,47,46,45},
                          {28,45,35,57,54,34,34,32,64,57,58,74,24,64,34,50},
                          {40,50,60,54,45,56,46,47,35,36,39,27,38,50,51,52},
                          {29,38,47,58,48,37,50,58,37,46,50,50,50,50,50,50},
                          {47,48,49,50,52,65,64,52,49,47,43,47,58,46,30,32},
                          {59,47,47,56,65,34,45,56,75,24,35,45,56,65,50,54},
                          {53,46,35,45,29,46,46,50,23,32,40,46,64,64,64,20},
                          {53,54,56,58,60,43,43,34,34,35,64,30,50,40,49,59},
                               {52,12,17,50,63,62,62,64,50,51,52,57,43,44,42,69}};

public static void main(String [] args)
{
    lol2 lol1 = new lol2();
}
public lol2()
{
    ArrayList<Integer> record = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    int max =0;
    for(int count = 0; count<10000; count++)
    {
        for(int startx=0; startx<16; startx++)
        {
            for(int starty =0; starty<16; starty++)
            {
                for(int a1 = 0; a1 <4; a1++) {
                    for(int a2 = 0; a2 <4; a2++) {
                        for(int a3 = 0; a3 <4; a3++) {
                            for(int a4 = 0; a4 <4; a4++) {
                                for(int a5 = 0; a5 <4; a5++) {
                                    for(int a6 = 0; a6 <4; a6++) {
                                        for(int a7 = 0; a7 <4; a7++) {
                                            for(int a8 = 0; a8 <4; a8++) {
                                                for(int a9 = 0; a9 <4; a9++) {
                                                    for(int a10 = 0; a10 <4; a10++) {
                                                        for(int a11 = 0; a11 <4; a11++) {
                                                            for(int a12 = 0; a12 <4; a12++) {
                                                                for(int a13 = 0; a13 <4; a13++) {
                                                                    for(int a14 = 0; a14 <4; a14++) {
                                                                        for(int a15 = 0; a15 <4; a15++) {
                                                                            for(int a16 = 0; a16 <4; a16++) {
                                                                                for(int a17 = 0; a17 <4; a17++) {
                                                                                    for(int a18 = 0; a18 <4; a18++) {
                                                                                        for(int a19 = 0; a19 <4; a19++) {
                                                                                            for(int a20 = 0; a20 <4; a20++) {
                                                                                                for(int a21 = 0; a21 <4; a21++) {
                                                                                                    for(int a22 = 0; a22 <4; a22++) {
                                                                                                        for(int a23 = 0; a23 <4; a23++) {
                                                                                                            for(int a24 = 0; a24 <4; a24++) {
                                                                                                                for(int a25 = 0; a25 <4; a25++) {
                                                                                                                    for(int a26 = 0; a26 <4; a26++) {
                                                                                                                        for(int a27 = 0; a27 <4; a27++) {
                                                                                                                            for(int a28 = 0; a28 <4; a28++) {
                                                                                                                                for(int a29 = 0; a29 <4; a29++) {
                                                                                                                                    for(int a30 = 0; a30 <4; a30++) {
                                                                                                                                        for(int a31 = 0; a31 <4; a31++) {
                                                                                                                                            for(int a32 = 0; a32 <4; a32++) {
                                                                                                                                                for(int a33 = 0; a33 <4; a33++) {
                                                                                                                                                    for(int a34 = 0; a34 <4; a34++) {
                                                                                                                                                        for(int a35 = 0; a35 <4; a35++) {
                                                                                                                                                            for(int a36 = 0; a36 <4; a36++) {
                                                                                                                                                                for(int a37 = 0; a37 <4; a37++) {
                                                                                                                                                                    for(int a38 = 0; a38 <4; a38++) {
                                                                                                                                                                        for(int a39 = 0; a39 <4; a39++) {
                                                                                                                                                                            System.out.println("SPAM");
                                                                                                                                                                            for(int a40 = 0; a40 <4; a40++) {
                                                                                                                                                                                for(int a41 = 0; a41 <4; a41++) {
                                                                                                                                                                                    for(int a42 = 0; a42 < 4; a42++){
                                                                                                                                                                                        for(int a43=0; a43<4; a43++){
                                                                                                                                                                                            for(int a44 =0; a44<4; a44++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                for(int a45=0; a45<4; a45++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                    for(int a46=0; a46<4; a46++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                        for(int a47=0; a47<4; a47++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                            for(int a48=0; a48<4; a48++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                                for(int a49=0; a49<4; a49++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    for(int a50=0; a50<4; a50++){
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        int[] pos = new int[2];
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        pos[0] = starty;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        pos[1] = startx;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ArrayList<Integer> past = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        int total = 0;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        String path = "" + a1 + a2+a3+a4+a5+a6+a7+a8+a9+a10+a11+a12+a13+a14+a15+a16+a17+a18+a19+a20+a21+a22+a23+a24+a25+a26+a27+a28+a29+a30+a31+a32+a33+a34+a35+a36+a37+a38+a39+a40+a41+a42+a43+a44+a45+a46+a47+a48+a49+a50;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        for(int i =0; i<50; i++)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                {

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    int random = Integer.parseInt(path.substring(i,i+1));
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    int switchcount = 0;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    past.add(100*pos[0] + pos[1]);
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        total+= square[pos[0]][pos[1]];

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if(random == 0)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            if(pos[0] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0]-1)*100+pos[1],past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                random++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                switchcount++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                pos[0]--;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if(random == 1)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            if(pos[0] == 15 || checkexists((pos[0]+1)*100+pos[1],past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                random++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                switchcount++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                pos[0]++;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if(random == 2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            if(pos[1] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0])*100+pos[1]-1,past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                random++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                switchcount++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                pos[1]--;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if(random == 3)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            if(pos[1] == 15 || checkexists((pos[0])*100+pos[1]+1,past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                if(switchcount >= 3)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    break;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    random = 0;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    if(pos[0] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0]-1)*100+pos[1],past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        random++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        switchcount++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        pos[0]--;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    if(random == 1)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if(pos[0] == 15 || checkexists((pos[0]+1)*100+pos[1],past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            random++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            switchcount++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            pos[0]++;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    if(random == 2)
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if(pos[1] == 0 || checkexists((pos[0])*100+pos[1]-1,past))
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            break;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            pos[1]--;

                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            else
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            {
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                pos[1]++;
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                        if (total>max) max = total;f
                                                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                                        }

                                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                                }
                                                                                                            }
                                                                                                        }
                                                                                                    }
                                                                                                }
                                                                                            }
                                                                                        }
                                                                                    }
                                                                                }
                                                                            }
                                                                        }
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for(int p = 0; p<record.size(); p++)
    {
        System.out.println(record.get(p));
    }
    System.out.println("\n\n" + max);

}
public boolean checkexists(int pos, ArrayList<Integer> past)
{
    for(int i=0; i<past.size(); i++)
    {
        if(past.get(i) == pos)
        {
            //System.out.println("TRUE");
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
/*public ArrayList<String> setint()
{
    ArrayList<String> bob = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(BigInteger i =1267650600228229401496703205376; ; i<2535301200456458802993406410752; i++)
    {
        String number = i + "";
        bob.add(BigInteger.toString(BigInteger.parseInt(number, 10), 4));
    }
    return bob;
}
*/
```

}

Comment: The only interesting thing in this question is your proposed solution.

Comment: Here's a serious question: can the line be diagonal?

Comment: is it really a spam , as pointed by @Treycos the println line says otherwise more info is required about `can be connected by a line`

Comment: I'm testing somthing but its going to take ages to execute...

Comment: I'm going to suggest that you read up on recursion, which might be helpful with this problem. This kind of solution might not be helpful in terms of speed, but at least the code won't be as monstrous.

Comment: Can values be negative?

Comment: So, you are concatenating 50 integer values into a string only to parse them out again one by one? … I have no words.

Comment: Nervermind, it was faster than what i expected

Comment: so treycos - what was the result?

Comment: i think you need one more for-loop

Comment: Thre sult is coming soon... or not, it takes ages to execute, just as planned, i'll edit if it end one day...

Comment: I get a path with a score of 2840 in less than 20 minutes on my machine. YMMV since you can basically trade memory for speed with the LRU_Cache, so if don't have as much memory to give to the LRU_Cache, it *may* run significantly slower on your machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDIT: Here is some sample code demonstrating some of the techniques I've outlined. It solves this problem reasonably well. While experimenting, I did find some improvements that are not in code below. Improving the speed/efficiency of this program is 100% possible, but left as an exercise to any future reader

```
import java.util.*;
public class SquareSolver {
/**
 * The LRU_Cache data structure is useful in a LOT of optimization problems, where storing all the problems you've solved so far
 * is infeasible, but there's significant time savings to be had if your program can
 * realize "Wait, I've solved this sub-problem already", and just re-use earlier answers.
 * It stores things, until it gets above LRUCacheSize, then it automatically ejects the least recently used entry.
 * This is strictly an optimization, because things get ejected from the cache automatically, you should not rely on
 * presence (or not) of an element for correctness.
 */
private HashMap<Integer, LRUCache> leastRecentlyUsedCache;
private Map<Integer, Integer> bestShortPathScores;
private Map<Integer, Integer> depthEarlyCutoffsMap;
private Map<Integer, Integer> depthCacheHitsMap;
private int squareSize, targetLength;
private Map<Coords, Integer> coordScores;
private Set<Coords> neighborOffsets;
private Path bestPath;
private boolean isLongPath;
private long startTime;
private long timeout;
private class LRUCache extends LinkedHashMap<Path, Integer>{
    private int LRUCacheSize;
    LRUCache(int LRUCacheSize){
        super(LRUCacheSize * 4 / 3, 0.75f, true);
       this.LRUCacheSize = LRUCacheSize;
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Map.Entry eldest) {
        return size() > LRUCacheSize;
    }
}
public SquareSolver(int LRUCacheSize, int squareSize, int targetLength) {
    neighborOffsets = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(new Coords[]{new Coords(-1, 0), new Coords(1, 0), new Coords(0, -1), new Coords(0, 1)}));
    this.targetLength = targetLength;
    this.squareSize = squareSize;
    leastRecentlyUsedCache = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i = 0; i <= targetLength; i++) {
        leastRecentlyUsedCache.put(i, new LRUCache(LRUCacheSize / targetLength));
    }
    coordScores = new HashMap<>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] testSquare = new int[][]{
            {50, 54, 46, 55, 45, 56, 44, 53, 47, 59, 41, 60, 40, 59, 41, 59},
            {47, 57, 46, 49, 52, 46, 53, 47, 53, 41, 59, 40, 60, 41, 59, 41},
            {56, 42, 54, 51, 48, 54, 47, 53, 53, 57, 48, 54, 49, 57, 46, 59},
            {48, 50, 52, 54, 56, 58, 57, 47, 48, 49, 48, 47, 46, 53, 52, 51},
            {50, 56, 50, 48, 49, 50, 51, 59, 42, 60, 39, 62, 38, 63, 38, 50},
            {60, 40, 50, 50, 50, 50, 60, 40, 55, 45, 55, 45, 56, 44, 56, 44},
            {60, 45, 46, 37, 56, 50, 43, 39, 50, 53, 56, 39, 50, 58, 39, 49},
            {26, 56, 54, 38, 48, 50, 67, 64, 32, 54, 50, 49, 48, 47, 46, 45},
            {28, 45, 35, 57, 54, 34, 34, 32, 64, 57, 58, 74, 24, 64, 34, 50},
            {40, 50, 60, 54, 45, 56, 46, 47, 35, 36, 39, 27, 38, 50, 51, 52},
            {29, 38, 47, 58, 48, 37, 50, 58, 37, 46, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50, 50},
            {47, 48, 49, 50, 52, 65, 64, 52, 49, 47, 43, 47, 58, 46, 30, 32},
            {59, 47, 47, 56, 65, 34, 45, 56, 75, 24, 35, 45, 56, 65, 50, 54},
            {53, 46, 35, 45, 29, 46, 46, 50, 23, 32, 40, 46, 64, 64, 64, 20},
            {53, 54, 56, 58, 60, 43, 43, 34, 34, 35, 64, 30, 50, 40, 49, 59},
            {52, 12, 17, 50, 63, 62, 62, 64, 50, 51, 52, 57, 43, 44, 42, 69}};
    SquareSolver testSolver = new SquareSolver(500 * 1000, 16, 50);
    Path bestPath = testSolver.solveSquare(testSquare, 30 * 1000);
    System.out.println("Best Score:\t" + bestPath.getScore());
    System.out.println("Best Path:\t" + bestPath.toString());
}

private boolean inSquare(Coords coords) {
    int x = coords.getX();
    int y = coords.getY();
    return x >= 0 && y >= 0 && x < squareSize && y < squareSize;
}

public void solveSquareHelper(Path currentPath) {
    // Base Case
    if (currentPath.size() == targetLength) {
        synchronized (bestPath) {
            if (currentPath.getScore() > bestPath.getScore()) {
                System.out.print(".");
                bestPath = currentPath;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    // Don't run forever.
    if (System.currentTimeMillis() > startTime + timeout){
        return;
    }

    // Least Recently Used Cache can save us a lot of work
    if (lru_hit(currentPath)) {
        return;
    }

    // Early Cutoff can save us a lot of work too
    if (can_early_cutoff(currentPath)) {
        return;
    }

    // Recursive Case
    expandLegalNeighbors(currentPath);
}

private void expandLegalNeighbors(Path currentPath) {
    Coords currentCoords = currentPath.getCurrentCoords();
    neighborOffsets.stream()
            .map(currentCoords::add)                    // Get all neighbors of current coords
            .filter(this::inSquare)                     // Filter out coords outside the square
            .filter(currentPath::doesNotContain)        // Filter out coords already in currentPath
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Coords::getProximityToOrigin)) // This order maximizes the usefulness of LRUCache
            .forEachOrdered(neighbor ->
                    solveSquareHelper(new Path(currentPath, neighbor)));
}

private boolean can_early_cutoff(Path currentPath) {
    int futurePathLength = targetLength - currentPath.size();
    int upperBoundFutureScore = bestShortPathScores.get(futurePathLength);
    if (currentPath.getScore() + upperBoundFutureScore <= bestPath.getScore()) {
        depthEarlyCutoffsMap.put(currentPath.size(), depthEarlyCutoffsMap.get(currentPath.size()) + 1);
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

private boolean lru_hit(Path currentPath) {
    LRUCache currentDepthCache = leastRecentlyUsedCache.get(currentPath.size());
    if (currentDepthCache.containsKey(currentPath)) {
        depthCacheHitsMap.put(currentPath.size(), depthCacheHitsMap.get(currentPath.size()) + 1);
        currentDepthCache.put(currentPath, currentDepthCache.get(currentPath) + 1);
        return true;
    } else {
        currentDepthCache.put(currentPath, 0);
    }
    return false;
}
public Path solveSquare(int[][] square, long timeout){
    Map<Integer, Integer> smallPathScores = new HashMap<>();
    smallPathScores.put(1, -10);
    for(int i =0; i < squareSize; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < squareSize; j++){
            if(square[i][j] > smallPathScores.get(1)){
                smallPathScores.put(1, square[i][j]);
            }
        }
    }
    Coords fakeCoords = new Coords(-10, -10);
    coordScores.put(fakeCoords, -10);
    Path bestSmallPath = new Path(fakeCoords);
    for(int i = 2; i < targetLength; i++){
        SquareSolver smallSolver = new SquareSolver(500 * 1000, squareSize, i);
        bestSmallPath = smallSolver.solveSquare(square, timeout * i, smallPathScores, bestSmallPath);
        smallPathScores.put(i, bestSmallPath.getScore());
        System.gc();
    }
    return solveSquare(square, timeout * targetLength, smallPathScores, bestSmallPath);
}
public Path solveSquare(int[][] square, long timeout, Map<Integer, Integer> shortPathScores, Path initialBestPath) {
    bestPath = initialBestPath;
    bestShortPathScores = shortPathScores;
    System.out.println("=============================Target Length:\t" + targetLength + "(Timeout:\t" + timeout/60000.0 + " minutes)===========================");
    System.out.println("Best Short Path Scores (for early cutoff):\t" + bestShortPathScores);
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    this.timeout = timeout;
    depthCacheHitsMap = new HashMap<>();
    depthEarlyCutoffsMap = new HashMap<>();
    for (int i = 1; i < targetLength; i++) {
        depthCacheHitsMap.put(i, 0);
        depthEarlyCutoffsMap.put(i, 0);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < squareSize; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < squareSize; j++) {
            coordScores.put(new Coords(i, j), square[i][j]);
        }
    }
    System.out.print("Expanding from best shorter node");
    expandLegalNeighbors(initialBestPath);
    System.out.println("Starting from every spot");
    coordScores.keySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Coords::getProximityToOrigin))
            .forEachOrdered(startingCoords -> solveSquareHelper(new Path(startingCoords)));
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println("Best Path:\t" + bestPath);
    System.out.println("Best Score:\t" + bestPath.getScore());
    System.out.println("LRU Cache stats:\t" + depthCacheHitsMap);
    System.out.println("Early Cutoff stats:\t" + depthEarlyCutoffsMap);
    return bestPath;
}

private class Coords implements Comparable<Coords> {
    private int x, y;
    private double proximityToOrigin;

    Coords(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.proximityToOrigin = Math.sqrt((x - squareSize/2) * (x - squareSize/2) + (y - squareSize/2) * (y - squareSize/2));
    }

    int getX() {
        return this.x;
    }

    int getY() {
        return this.y;
    }

    double getProximityToOrigin() {
        return proximityToOrigin;
    }

    Coords add(Coords other) {
        return new Coords(this.x + other.x, this.y + other.y);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Coords o) {
        int xdiff = this.x - o.x;
        if (xdiff == 0) return this.y - o.y;
        else return xdiff;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Coords) {
            Coords o = (Coords) other;
            return this.x == o.x && this.y == o.y;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.x * squareSize + this.y;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "(" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ")";
    }
}

private class Path {
    private TreeSet<Coords> usedCoords;
    private Coords currentCoords;
    private int score;

    Path(Coords newCoords) {
        this.usedCoords = new TreeSet<>();
        usedCoords.add(newCoords);
        currentCoords = newCoords;
        this.score = coordScores.get(newCoords);
    }

    Path(Path previousPath, Coords newCoords) {
        this(newCoords);
        this.usedCoords.addAll(previousPath.usedCoords);
        this.score += previousPath.score;
    }

    Coords getCurrentCoords() {
        return this.currentCoords;
    }

    int size() {
        return usedCoords.size();
    }

    int getScore() {
        return this.score;
    }

    boolean doesNotContain(Coords coords) {
        return !usedCoords.contains(coords);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.usedCoords.toString();
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.usedCoords.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        if (other instanceof Path) {
            Path o = (Path) other;
            return this.usedCoords.equals(o.usedCoords) && this.currentCoords.equals(o.currentCoords);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Some key insights that allow us to do something more efficient than brute force:

**Insight** Two sub-paths with the same current node and same set of used nodes, have the same top-score.

**How We Use This** Use an LRU_Cache which recognizes paths which use the same nodes and have the same current node, as equivalent. This causes MANY early cutoffs, at depths as early as 4. Subtrees whose root node is at a depth of 4 with respect to the main tree contain 3^46 paths each. Pruning an appreciable fraction of them out is huge.

**Insight** A sub-path of length k can only obtain a maximum score of sub-path.score + best_length_n-k_path.score

**How We Use This** First solve for the best path of length 2, then use that to find the best path of length 3. Use both of them to find the best path of length 4, etc. You can early cutoff anytime a current path of length k cannot exceed the max score even with your previous best n-k length path added on. Solving for n = 2, 3, 4, 5 ... 50 seems like a lot more work than just solving n = 50 directly, but for this problem it turns out the savings from early pruning are worth more.

Comment: Great post. I've been thinking about this one for a few days. I knew pruning the search space would be one good way to make the naive solution actually calculable, but hadn't really thought of any good heuristics for the pruning. This seems like a good place to start!

Comment: Updated with sample code which performs MUCH better than a brute force solution. It still isn't perfect though, and tiny tweaks can have huge impacts on its runtime. The best answer I got was 2840 using this code.

Comment: Nice. I wrote a DP solution a few days ago but didn't post it because it only gets 2810 (due to shortcomings with DP for this problem mentioned in other posts here). Somebody on Reddit wrote a greedy lookahead version that gets around 2825 (with lookahead distance that doesn't take years to solve), but 2840 is the best I've seen yet. I'm tempted to try some improvements to my DP algorithm but I don't really think that solution will ever be ideal for this.

Comment: My code terminates long before the timeout, so, barring a bug in my code, 2840 should be the maximum (The algorithm is designed to exhaustively search all possible solutions, except cutoff early where it provably won't miss a better path, or timeout. If it terminates before timeout, I think it's searched everything exhaustively).

Comment: What reddit thread had this problem? I might cross post this solution, or, if language doesn't matter, a much cleaner Python solution. I struggled through this Java version XD.

Comment: Sorry, I should have posted it: https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/57d9jv/interesting_16x16_grid_sum_problem/

Answer (score 2):

If the lines can't be diagonal, here's a way to do it
It (tries to) checks EVERY possibility:

Test.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test {
    private int[][] square =    
       {{50,54,46,55,45,56,44,53,47,59,41,60,40,59,41,59},
        {47,57,46,49,52,46,53,47,53,41,59,40,60,41,59,41},
        {56,42,54,51,48,54,47,53,53,57,48,54,49,57,46,59},
        {48,50,52,54,56,58,57,47,48,49,48,47,46,53,52,51},
        {50,56,50,48,49,50,51,59,42,60,39,62,38,63,38,50},
        {60,40,50,50,50,50,60,40,55,45,55,45,56,44,56,44},
        {60,45,46,37,56,50,43,39,50,53,56,39,50,58,39,49},
        {26,56,54,38,48,50,67,64,32,54,50,49,48,47,46,45},
        {28,45,35,57,54,34,34,32,64,57,58,74,24,64,34,50},
        {40,50,60,54,45,56,46,47,35,36,39,27,38,50,51,52},
        {29,38,47,58,48,37,50,58,37,46,50,50,50,50,50,50},
        {47,48,49,50,52,65,64,52,49,47,43,47,58,46,30,32},
        {59,47,47,56,65,34,45,56,75,24,35,45,56,65,50,54},
        {53,46,35,45,29,46,46,50,23,32,40,46,64,64,64,20},
        {53,54,56,58,60,43,43,34,34,35,64,30,50,40,49,59},
        {52,12,17,50,63,62,62,64,50,51,52,57,43,44,42,69}};

    int result = 0;

    Test()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++)
                search(new Position(i,j), new ArrayList<Position>(), 0); //Starts at every position
        System.out.println(result);
    }

    public void search(Position actual, ArrayList<Position> checked, int sum){
    checked.add(actual); //Add the actual position to avoid going through it multiple times
    sum += square[actual.row][actual.column];

    if (checked.size() != 50)
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            for (int j = -1; j < 2; j += 2){ //Checks every direction
                boolean checkable = true;
                Position newpos;

                if (i != 0)
                    newpos = new Position(actual.row, actual.column + j);
                else
                    newpos = new Position(actual.row + j, actual.column);

                if (newpos.row >= 0 && newpos.column >= 0 && newpos.row <= 15 && newpos.column <= 15){
                    for (Position pos : checked)
                        if(pos.equals(newpos)) //If the new position has already been calculated
                            checkable = false;

                    if(checkable)
                        search(newpos, new ArrayList<Position>(checked), sum); //If the position haven't been checked, starts a new search
                }
            }

    if (sum > result){
        result = sum;
        System.out.println(sum);
    }
}
```

}

Position.java

```
public class Position{
    public int row, column;

    Position(int x, int y){
        row = x;
        column = y;
    }

    public boolean equals(Position pos) {
        return pos.row == this.row && pos.column == this.column;
    }
}
```

Main.java

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new Test();
    }
}
```

Current output : `2578`
Comment if i forgot something/have any suggestions/questions
The execution time is weirdly low

EDIT : When i print the size of the checked list using this:

```
    if (sum > result){
        result = sum;
        System.out.println(checked.size());
    }
```

Its going above 50... although its not supposed to. Any idea?
Here, `count + checked.size()` should ALWAYS be equals to 50

EDIT 2 :
Found it!
I just had to create a new array for each search:

```
if(checkable)
    search(newpos, count, new ArrayList<Position>(checked), sum);
```

Just realise that its going to check 16*16*3^50 cases... meh, worth a try

Comment: Are you kidding? Just playing around with it by hand I get to a score of 2756.  (Sorry for the eye cancer due to the colors, but seeing the scale helps intuition, and the blue path is best to distinguish from the "background".)  https://www.dropbox.com/s/hv49sxiyx5o277o/aa_only_2756.png?dl=0 and you can trivially improve that by 15 (remove the 59, add the 74)

Comment: Damn, i don't know what is wrong in my program then... it litterraly checks everything. This might be a really dumb thing but i can't see it...

Comment: I didn't check your code but did it terminate? A brute force search would take forever on this problem.

Comment: Thats why i think there's a problem here, it only takes around 3 seconds to execute... weird, and if you're wondering why the other answers were downvoted, its not for revenge or anything, none of them gave a real answer

Comment: *Its going above 50* That's because the same `checked` array is passed through all your recursive calls. It gets filled pretty quickly, because it's not "unfilled" when you backtrack. That is indeed a good reason for your program to terminate quickly.

Comment: I found the error, thank you @Patrice Gahide, its executing for a few minutes now ^^

Comment: Well, sit yourself down comfortably ;) It will go on for an order of `3^50 * 2^8` calculations. Say your computer can handle 300 MIPS, and that one instruction is enough to handle one iteration of yours (lower bound, of course). Then your program will run for something like 20 billion years.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like a good place to start would be finding the areas of highest intensity.

A strategy could be ranking each location as a sum of its neighbors multiplied by a [Gaussian distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function) centered at each location:

```
rank(a, b) = 0
for j in -16 to 16:
    for k in -16 to 16:
        rank(a, b) += value(a+j, b+k)*exp(-((a)^2+(b)^2)/constant)
```

Where `value(x, y)` is a value in the original map, and `constant` is a decay factor. And values that fall outside of the original bounds are considered zero.

After doing this for each pixel a new `rank` map is formed. The highest values from this map will indicate the areas on the original map which contain, on average, higher numbered neighbors. Traveling between these points will make it more likely for you to guess higher numbered locations correctly.